# How can I learn about SQL Reporting Services?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I don't know anything about it and would like to learn how. I don't know what I need to install or configure, or how to use it. Is there any advice to get started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Getting Started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb522672.aspx)

[Tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/bb522859.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

[SQL Server books online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx). Best resource for anything SQL Server.

Here is a direct link to the [Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx) section.